# JPA and SQLite3 - Wrong date

Tags: sqlite, jpa, eclipselink

A date field in my entity class is defined as below:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "LAST_EXECUTED")
private Date lastExecuted = new Date();
```

However, when it is persisted to a SQLite3 database through JPA, the database value is always '1899-12-30'. Do you have any ideas why?

In the database, the field is defined as `DATETIME`.

I've tried using both SqliteJDBC and Xerial SQLite JDBC.

**Update:**  After turning on SQL debugging in EclipseLink JPA, and turning off parameter binding, it looks like dates are inserted as following:

```
insert into run (last_executed) values ('{ts ''2012-02-17 10:34:58.013''}');
```

which, if inserted, manually in SQLite, gives the date '1899-12-30'.

Of course, any workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Obviously you're using a particular implementation of JPA there, and each JPA implementation would give different results. Consequently actually mentioning which JPA implementation would be a help ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry; it's EclipseLink JPA.

Comment: Can't help you since DataNucleus JPA does an INSERT as "INSERT INTO A (LAST_EXECUTED) VALUES ('2012-02-17 13:41:09.453')" and upon retrieval has all of the data it had at persist

Comment: '1899-12-30' is the zero date, so what is the data type in the database?  Chances are it is only storing the time information and converting the date to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date looks correct in the insert, so seems to be some kind of SQLite issue.  You should normally use parameter binding, it seems SQLite does allow Timestamp to be bound, or ignores the DATE portion.  What if you use TemporalType.DATE?

Perhaps try through raw JDBC to see exactly what your JDBC drivers issue are?

For the printed syntax if not using parameter binding, you can customize this by creating your own DatabasePlatform subclass.  The syntax you printed is the standard JDBC timestamp syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that it is a java.util.Date and not a java.sql.Date?

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "LAST_EXECUTED")
private java.util.Date lastExecuted = new Date();
```

What does the debug output look like if you turn parameter binding back on?

Answer (score -1):

Use **smalldatetime** solve the problem~~~ Try it.