# JPA and SQLite date issues

Tags: jpa, sqlite, temporal

I have a Entity class in which a Calendar field is annotated with @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE).

I am using Sqlite3 for my DB. The column in the DB is a Text type.
Whenever I persist the Entity object, the value for that Calendar field always gets persisted as 1375900200000.

I have tried with different combinations of @Temporal types and Table column types. I looked at [JPA and SQLite3 - Wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319850/jpa-and-sqlite3-wrong-date) to no avail.I am using Toplinks as my JPA provider. Any pointers on what could be wrong?